# Cythonizing function containing too many arrays

Tags: cythonize

Running setup.py on the code below takes some seconds to finish; however, by increasing number of arrays to 20k, .pyd is not generated after 2 hours of running the setup on windows XP 32 bit. Should I use a specific definition for the arrays?

```
import numpy
import scipy.interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
y = [0.1, 0.2, .3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, .7, 0.8, .9, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9]

def interpolate(DATA,x_new,y_new):
    var1 = DATA[0]
    var2 = DATA[1]
    f = interp2d(y,x,var1,kind='linear')
    k1 = f(y_new,x_new)     
    f = interp2d(y,x,var2,kind='linear')
    k2 = f(y_new,x_new)   
    return (k1[0],k2[0])

def function(condition1,condition2,param1,param2):
    Data1_var1=[[6L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, .7, 5.7, 4.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 9.5, 7.2, 5.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 8, 7, 5.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [8L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, .8, .1, 4.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [6L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 8, .8, 5.4, 4.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 6.3, 5.2, 4.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 8.4, 6.8, 5.6, 4.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [6L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 9.2, 6, 6.3, 5L, 4.2, 3.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [3L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L, .8, 8.3, 7L, .6, 4.8, 4.1, 3.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 8.9, 7.7, 6.5, 5.6, 5L, 4.6, 4.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 10L, 9.2, 8.1, 6.9, .1, .6, 5.1, 4.6, .2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
    Data1_var2=[[6L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, .7, 5.7, 4.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 9.5, 7.2, 5.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 8, 7, 5.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [8L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, .8, .1, 4.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [6L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 8, .8, 5.4, 4.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 6.3, 5.2, 4.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 8.4, 6.8, 5.6, 4.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [6L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 9.2, 6, 6.3, 5L, 4.2, 3.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [3L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L, .8, 8.3, 7L, .6, 4.8, 4.1, 3.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 8.9, 7.7, 6.5, 5.6, 5L, 4.6, 4.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 10L, 9.2, 8.1, 6.9, .1, .6, 5.1, 4.6, .2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

    Data2_var1=[[9L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, .7, 5.7, 4.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [3L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 9.5, 7.2, 5.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 8, 7, 5.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [8L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, .8, .1, 4.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [6L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 8, .8, 5.4, 4.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 6.3, 5.2, 4.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 8.4, 6.8, 5.6, 4.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [6L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 9.2, 6, 6.3, 5L, 4.2, 3.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [3L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L, .8, 8.3, 7L, .6, 4.8, 4.1, 3.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 8.9, 7.7, 6.5, 5.6, 5L, 4.6, 4.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 10L, 9.2, 8.1, 6.9, .1, .6, 5.1, 4.6, .2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
    Data2_var2=[[4L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, .7, 5.7, 4.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [6L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 9.5, 7.2, 5.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 8, 7, 5.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [8L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, .8, .1, 4.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [6L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 8, .8, 5.4, 4.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 6.3, 5.2, 4.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 8.4, 6.8, 5.6, 4.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [6L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 9.2, 6, 6.3, 5L, 4.2, 3.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [3L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L, .8, 8.3, 7L, .6, 4.8, 4.1, 3.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 8.9, 7.7, 6.5, 5.6, 5L, 4.6, 4.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 10L, 9.2, 8.1, 6.9, .1, .6, 5.1, 4.6, .2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
    
if condition1:
    if condition2:
        out = interpolate(Data1,param1,param2)
    else:
        out = interpolate(Data2,param1,param2)
```